# Map spread array to numbers

Tags: javascript

When mapping an array containing integers and strings I want to cast only the numbers.

Assume the array ['55', 'abc'] is passed as a param to a function.

How can I use the spread operator and get the same results?

"Run code snippet" and notice that with the spread operator, 55 is not cast to a number.

```js
console.log(['55', 'abc'].map(val => isNaN(val) ? val : Number(val)))
console.log(...[['55', 'abc']].map(val => isNaN(val) ? val : Number(val)))
```

Comment: What do you want to use the spread operator for? What's the goal?

Comment: `console.log(...array)` is equivalent to `console.log(array[0], array[1], ..., array[length-1])` You are passing each item of the array returned by `map` as a argument to `console.log`.

Comment: Your second example has an array containing an array, not an array containing integers and strings. Did you mean `console.log(...['55', 'abc'].map(…))`?

Comment: `console.log(...[['55', 'abc']].map(val => isNaN(val) ? val : Number(val)))`
   
In here, your `val` is going to be `['55', 'abc']`. So, it works right.

Comment: Are you trying to do `[['55', 'abc']].flat().map(...)`?

Comment: In the second line of code, `val` in `isNaN(val)` is `['55', 'abc']`, so you are passing an array to `isNaN` function which tries to convert it to a number by first converting it to a primitive value which is done by calling `val.toString()` which converts `val` into a string `55,abc` and then this string is converted to a number `Number('55,abc')` which results in `NaN` value, so `val` is returned from the `.map()` method and that is what you see on the console.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I use the spread operator and get the same results?

You can't. Spread (which is syntax, not an operator) doesn't do mapping. It spreads out values. For mapping, stick with `map` (what you have in the first line of your code). (Or if you were starting with something that was just *array-like* without actually being an array, you might use `Array.from` passing in a mapping callback. But your starting point in your example is an actual array.)

The reason your second line doesn't work is that you're calling `map` on the outer array, which has an array in it, so `val` in the callback is that array. `isNaN(['55, 'abc'])` ends up being `isNaN('55,abc')` which is `true` because `'55,abc'` when converted to the `number` type is `NaN`. So the callback returns the inner array unchanged.

Your first line creates a new array with the values mapped the way you seem to want them to be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't spreading it into a new array. The below gives the desired result.

```js
console.log(['55', 'abc'].map(val => isNaN(val) ? val : Number(val)))
console.log([...['55', 'abc']].map(val => isNaN(val) ? val : Number(val)))
```

Comment: You never should spread an array literal into an array literal. That's just unnecessary.

Comment: @Bergi I agree, my assumption is OP was using an array literal to make the question easier to understand. Not that this is the actual code.

Comment: This is true, I don't have the easiest way to manipulate the array being passed in, but it might be the best / only route